# How to send shortcut keys in the current web browser?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to send some shortcut keys to open a new tab in chrome, using selenium in python. I open up facebook, then I log in, then I want to open a new tab where I can pass the url of one of my friend so that I can view his profile. I wrote the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import getpass

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#opening browser and loging into the account
def login():
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")
    elem.send_keys("myUsername")
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
    password.send_keys("myPassword")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

def scout():
    scroll =     driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/some.friend")
    driver.implicitly_wait(8)

login()
scout()
```

But it gives me the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I made the browser wait implicitly but still it's unable to find the tag. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try calling `WebDriverWait` instead of `find_element_by_css_selector` in order to find elements. It calls `find_element_by_<method>` every half a second until given timeout. That way you don't have to gamble with `implicitly_wait` or `time.sleep()`.
Regarding your open new tab problem - you cannot send ctrl + t to chromedriver, it simply wouldn't do anything (it would work on firefox though). I've encountered this problem before, and the best solution I found is to search for a link in the website itself, so if you're on Facebook you can use that F icon at the top left. Then you can send ctrl + shift + click to open that in a new tab.

```
        from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
        actions = ActionChains(driver);
        actions.move_to_element(link)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ Keys.SHIFT)
        actions.click(link)
        actions.perform()
```

From there you should just switch tabs using

```
        tabs = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(tabs[<index>])
```

Comment: Quick question: is the type(driver) inside the ActionChains(driver) a webdriver element?

Comment: No. It is the driver object. The "link" would be the web element